# How to configure PHP Storm for working and debugging remote project (existent PHP files)

Tags: php, intellij-idea, ssh, phpstorm, remote-debugging

I have been using a lot of IDEs, also a lot of from Intellij IDEA. But I cannot configure my PhpStorm IDE to work with remote project. I have tried several times for several hours, but still doesn't get desired result.

I have remote web server, let it has name `mysuperdomain.com`. I have ftp access and if it required I can get ssh access.

I have web site/application on the this remote server, nothing magic. Simple location `/var/www/mysuperdomain/public/`. I have some common web file formats here js, php , html, css... So simple web page. I am interested in editing and debugging project remotely.

So I want to create project on my local machine, configure it to access remote server directory with project `/var/www/mysuperdomain/public/project` and files there, so I can edit them and all changes will be saved and synchronized with the remote server.

I have used SSH access to open files in SublimeText edit them, and each time I pressed Ctrl+S changes have been affected to the remote server files. I need the same in PhpStorm + DEBUGGING (variables values, breakpoints..)

I have tried to follow official tutorials, but still cannot get it working completely as I need.

Comment: You need to read these first: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Generally speaking: you need to have files locally to be able to edit them and use code completion etc. So .. you download them all to your local PC and work with them. Then you can setup Deployment entry, mark it as Default for this project and enable "automatic deployment on save" if necessary in deployment options. Please note that in recently released v9 you can edit files directly from remote without downloading it into your project -- file will be downloaded in separate location and opened from there. More on this: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/04/remote-edit-in-phpstorm-9-eap/

Comment: For remote debugging -- you have to have xdebug or zend debugger to be installed and configured on your remote host. Link #2 has all the info (well, try this nicer looking one as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/quickstart/debugger.html )